Tracking local changes in git to a remote branch without pushing to remote
So this may be really obvious to people, but I find myself regularly wanting a workflow where I can easily:

Pull changes from a remote branch
Maintain local changes to that branch
Pulling changes doesn't create merge conflicts
Not commit changes to that remote branch
Have 0% risk pushing those local changes to the remote branch

At present I tend to keep changes local stash and pull and manage merge conflicts, this is really quite painful however. So I'm wondering if there's a good workflow that people could suggest.

The easiest is to have a local branch into which you pull the remote changes when ever you think it is time to do so.

You could branch out of that remote branch locally:
$ git checkout origin/some_remote_branch -b my_local_branch
branch 'my_local_branch' set up to track 'origin/some_remote_branch'.
Switched to a new branch 'my_local_branch'

And now you can work on your local branch. Pushing won't affect some_remote_branch, because you're working on a different, local, branch.
You can pull changes and rebase your local branch on the remote one at will.
There's no way to 100% guarantee there will be no merge conflicts - there's always a chance of the remote branch and your local work changing the same piece of code. However, you can always deal with that locally when it happens, or at worst, just start over with a new local branch.
